# My MacBook Pro makes 3 successive tones, a 5 second pause (repeating)

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

My MacBook Pro makes 3 successive tones, a 5 second pause (repeating).

According to Apple, this indicates RAM does not pass a data integrity check.

So how can I fix it?

Comment: If it's reporting the RAM is bad then obviously the RAM will need to be replaced.  How you go about it depends on which model MacBook Pro you have and whether or not it under warranty.  Since you didn't include that information it's difficult to be more specific, sans spelling out every option.

Comment: just now it started showing the screen then it again does the same thing I mentioned.Now I couldn't make it show the screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three beeps on startup is typically a memory self-test error symptom.

This article is providing some tools to test your RAM :

http://www.cnet.com/news/troubleshooting-tools-memtest-and-rember/

Comment: I also guess it should be a bad ram not faulty ram..somehow have to deal with it without really pulling the ram out..any ideas

Comment: @sathishkumar_kingmaker, What's "_I also guess it should be a bad ram not faulty ram._" supposed to mean?  Faulty/Bad in the context of RAM errors is tantamount to the same thing.  You still haven't stated what model Mac you have and the bottom line is if it's user serviceable you can try removing the RAM, cleaning the contacts with a rubber erasure and reseating it.  If the RAM is soldered to the main logic board, then it will have to be properly serviced.

Comment: mac book pro 2012 model I guess

Comment: @sathishkumar_kingmaker you can use http://mactracker.ca to know your mac model...